# Can you see the service account that triggers a cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-tasks

I have a bunch of gcloud and firebase predefined service accounts and I have to know which one calls a cloud function triggered by a cloud task so that I can give the cloud function invoker role. Is that possible or do I have to generate a new service account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify the service account that Cloud Tasks uses to invoke when queueing the task (see [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#token)):

```
  {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url,
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail: '<your-sa>@<your-project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
      },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to display the service account that call the Cloud Functions (especially with the audit logs), and I'm going to open a feature request for that.

Anyway, you can at least achieve this in your code. When the request is authenticated, you received this header

```
Authorization: bearer <token header>.<token body>.SIGNATURE_REMOVED_BY_GOOGLE
```

As you can see, because the token has been validated by google, and to prevent any reusability later on, the signature is redacted. But, it's not the important part, just donc try to validate the JWT token!

The idea here is to get the Token body (look at the dot `.` separation) and to decode it in base 64. You will get a JSON like this

```
{
   "iss":"https://accounts.google.com",
   "azp":"32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "aud":"32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "sub":"109283856132013660815",
   "email":"<the email of the requester>",
   "email_verified":true,
   "at_hash":"S83kJm6cdV18gyelCPNoaA",
   "iat":1617349064,
   "exp":1617352664
}
```

Get this part `"email":"<the email of the requester>"` and log it. Job done!